# What is a good online cloud based service for testing Android apps on real devices?

Tags: android

How do I replicate Nexus 5 images rotation issue when I don't have a Nexus 5?
I have a bug reported that images taken within my app are turned upside down when using Nexus 5. I have 6 devices at hand but not this one, and all 6 work just fine.
How can I replicate this issue, using a good, reliable online service that provides developers with real devices to test on?

Comment: use emulators like genymotion.

Comment: You might wish to explain, via a [mcve], how "images" are "taken" within your app. If by this you are referring to using a camera, your way to replicate the issue is to buy a Nexus 5. I test camera work on [about 50 devices](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/blob/master/docs/CompatibilityStatus.md) and keep adding more.

Comment: I'm sorry for not providing code, but I don't want an answer of how to fix this issue, I can fix it, as long as I reproduce it first, my question is how do I emulate a Nexus 5 behavior without buying the real device. Are there any online services for that?

Comment: Is it only for a specific nexus 5 device? in such case device hardware(accelerometer) could be defective. I have faced this issue on a device I owned.

Comment: That is an interesting case, however, it has happened on a few nexus 5 devices (and on some - not)... But generally, its not just about Nexus 5, maybe tomorrow there will be a problem with Samsung 3, I guess what I was trying to ask is, what reliable online service can I use in order to test on real devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has the [Cloud Test Lab](https://developers.google.com/cloud-test-lab/) which allows you to test different orientations on real devices, including the Nexus 5.

Answer (score 0):

An emulator like [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) has the device you require and many others too.

Comment: Genymotion just provides a VM with similar parameters like CPU and Screen size, but doesnt emulate the custom behavior of the device in question.